# How to check room availability using PHP JAVA SCRIPT AND QUERY

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am building hotel reservation system using PHP JAVASCRIPT and MYSQLi.
i have a page where user have to Define his search criteria like search available room by guest  by children by city by price by room type. till now i successfully implement but problem is how to check room availability using checkin and checkout date.

Here is the code for searching room by guest  by children by city by price and by room type. i have no idea to check availability using my code.

HTML CODE for search criteria as :

For Price:

```
<div class="checkbox">  
<select id="price">
<option value=""> Select Range of Price in Rs</opiton>
<option value="1000-1999">1000-1999 </option>
<option value="2000-2999">2000-2999 </option>
<option value="3000-3999">3000-3999 </option>
<option value="4000-4999">4000-4999 </option>
<option value="5000-5999">5000-5999 </option>
<option value="6000 +">6000+</option>
</select>
</div>
```

same code for count of children , count of adults , city and room type

For Check in Date and Check Out date:

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label for="ch7">Check-in Date</label>
<input  type="text" class="datepickerIn" placeholder="Check-in Date" id="checkin" name="checkin" >
<label for="ch7">Check-out Date</label>
<input  type="text" class="datepickerOut" placeholder="Check-out Date" id="checkout" name="checkout" >
 </div>
```

Java Script Code for ajax call using ID.

JAVA Script for Checkin and check out date:

```
 //Ajax call when user changes the check in and check out date
    $('#checkout').change(function(){
        var hotel_city = document.getElementById("hotel_city").value;
        var Room_Type_Name = document.getElementById("Room_Type_Name").value;
        var count_of_travels = document.getElementById("count_of_travels").value;
        var count_of_childerns = document.getElementById("count_of_childerns").value;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        var checkin = document.getElementById("checkin").value;
        var checkout = document.getElementById("checkout").value;

       var obj = { "hotel_city": hotel_city, "Room_Type_Name": Room_Type_Name, "count_of_travels": count_of_travels,"count_of_childerns":count_of_childerns,"price":price,"checkin":checkin,"checkout":checkout};
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
        $.ajax({

            url: "searchHotelsByDates.php",
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST',
            data: myJSON,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

SQL: Tables  are hotels[hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_city]
room [room_id,Hotel_Id(FK),facilities,room_type(FK),count_of_travels,count_of_childerns]
room_type [Room_Type_Id,Room_Type_Name]
reservation [reservation_id,check_in,check_out,room_id(FK),hotel_id(FK),User_Email(FK)]

```
session_start();
    include "required/connection.php";



    $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    //Decoding received JSON to array
    $response = json_decode($str_json,true); 
    //Get values

    $hotel_city = $response['hotel_city'];
    $Room_Type_Name = $response['Room_Type_Name'];  
    $count_of_travels = $response['count_of_travels'];  
    $count_of_childerns= $response['count_of_childerns'];
    $price= $response['price']; 
    $split_price=explode("-",$price);
    $min = $split_price[0];
   $max = $split_price[1];
   $checkin =$response['checkin'];
   $checkout =$response['checkout'];

    //Concatenate sql string considering users inputs
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
    if($hotel_city!=="" || $count_of_travels !=="" || $Room_Type_Name!=="" ||$count_of_childerns!==""||$min!==""||$max!=="" ||$checkin!=="" || $checkout!=="" ) {
        $sql = "SELECT *.reservation, room.room_id,room.short_description,room.count_of_travels,room.count_of_childerns,room.price,hotels.hotel_id,hotels.hotel_name,hotels.hotel_city,hotels.hotel_picture,room_type.Room_Type_Id,room_type.Room_Type_Name FROM hotels INNER JOIN room ON room.Hotel_Id=hotels.hotel_id INNER JOIN room_type on room.room_type=room_type.Room_Type_Id INNER JOIN on  reservation  Where";

    }
     if($hotel_city!=="" && $count_of_travels !=="" && $Room_Type_Name!=="" && $count_of_childerns!=="") {
         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels' AND Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name' && count_of_childerns='$count_of_childerns' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";

         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels' AND Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name' && count_of_childerns='$count_of_childerns' AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels' AND Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name' && count_of_childerns='$count_of_childerns' AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
    else if($hotel_city!=="" && $count_of_travels !=="" && $Room_Type_Name!=="" ) {
         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels' AND Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name'  ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";

         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels' AND Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name'  AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels' AND Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name'  AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
     else if($hotel_city!=="" && $count_of_travels !==""  ) {
         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels'   ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";

         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels'  AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city' AND count_of_travels='$count_of_travels'   AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
     else if($hotel_city!=="" ) {


         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city'    ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";

         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city'  AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " hotel_city='$hotel_city'    AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
         else if($count_of_travels!=="" ) {


         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " count_of_travels='$count_of_travels'    ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";

         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " count_of_travels='$count_of_travels'  AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " count_of_travels='$count_of_travels'    AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
    else if($Room_Type_Name!=="" ) {
         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name'    ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name'  AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " Room_Type_Name='$Room_Type_Name'    AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
     else if($count_of_childerns!=="" ) {
         if($min=="" && $max=="")
         {
             $sql =  $sql.  " count_of_childerns='$count_of_childerns'    ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
         }
         else
         {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " count_of_childerns='$count_of_childerns'  AND price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " count_of_childerns='$count_of_childerns'    AND price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
         }

    }
     else if($min!=="" &&  $max!=="" ) {
             if($min!=="" && $max=="")
             {
                  $split_min=explode("+",$min);
                  $sql =  $sql.  " price >= '$split_min[0]' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name";
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =  $sql.  " price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max' ORDER by hotels.hotel_name,room_type.Room_Type_Name"; 
             }
    }
    else
    {
         $sql = "SELECT room.room_id,room.short_description,room.count_of_travels,room.count_of_childerns,room.price,hotels.hotel_id,hotels.hotel_name,hotels.hotel_city,hotels.hotel_picture,room_type.Room_Type_Id,room_type.Room_Type_Name FROM hotels INNER JOIN room ON room.Hotel_Id=hotels.hotel_id INNER JOIN room_type on room.room_type=room_type.Room_Type_Id";

    }
  //  echo $sql;
  //exit;

        $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           ?>





   <article class="one-third">

<figure><a href="hotel.php?id=<?php echo $row["room_id"]; echo ';' ; echo $row["hotel_id"]; echo";";  echo $row["Room_Type_Id"]; ?>" title=""><img src="admin/images/Hotels/<?php echo $row['hotel_picture']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['hotel_name']; ?>" /></a></figure>
<div class="details">
<h3><?php echo $row['hotel_name']; ?>
<span class="stars">
<i class="material-icons">&#xE838;</i>
<i class="material-icons">&#xE838;</i>
<i class="material-icons">&#xE838;</i>
<i class="material-icons">&#xE838;</i>
<i class="material-icons">&#xE838;</i>
</span>
 </h3>
<span class="address">Type•<?php echo $row['Room_Type_Name'] ?></span>
<span class="address">Adults Allowed:<?php echo $row['count_of_travels'] ?></span>
<span class="address">Children Allowed:<?php echo $row['count_of_childerns'] ?></span>
 <span class="address">City: <?php echo $row['hotel_city'] ?>  •  <a href="map.php">Show on map</a></span>
<span class="rating"> 8 /10</span>
<span class="price">Price per room per night from  <em>Rs:<?php echo $row['price']; ?></em> </span>
<div class="description">
 <p><?php echo $row['short_description']; ?> </p>
</div>

<a href="hotel.php?id=<?php echo $row["room_id"]; echo ';' ; echo $row["hotel_id"]; echo";";  echo $row["Room_Type_Id"]; ?>" class="gradient-button">Book Now</a>
</div>
</article>
```

i know my explanation is very long but its important to write all my logic here which may help you to understand.

problem is what query should i use to check room availability using checkin date and checkout date and where this query is to be used? i have some idea that query contain joins with reservation table but i don't know how to use.
Please help

Thanks

Comment: Try creating a [mcve].

Comment: This post contains too much code. You need to narrow the issue down.

Comment: We'll help you when you narrow down the problem, as requested. Are you really asking how to write a SQL query to check availability of a suitable room between those dates? If so then actually 90% of your code is irrelevant. Focus on the SQL and provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: @ADyson exactly im asking about to  write a SQL query to check availability of a suitable room between those dates

Comment: Ok then well please amend your question and code samples accordingly then. The HTML, JS etc is irrelevant. In fact the PHP is mostly irrelevant too - this can be tested within MySQL only to begin with.

Comment: Also...what have you researched or tried so far? This kind of "availability" problem is quite common, especially in respect to things like room bookings. I'd be surprised if you couldn't get some hints, tips or even solutions online already. Basically it's an overlapping problem - you want to exclude rooms where the dates of any existing booking for that room overlap the requested dates, even just by one day.